# Task Manager Up Time differs from systeminfo System Boot Time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

In troubleshooting some issues with a Windows Server 2008 R2 box, I noticed that the Up Time in Task Manager was huge whereas the System Boot Time in `systeminfo` is seemingly correct. Can anyone tell me why these might be different? This *is* a virtual server.

[image]

Comment: What is your issue? 266 hours are eleven days, Nov. 22 + 11 days is today.

Comment: I missed that, but typically taskmgr adds a days indicator when up for 24 hours DD:HH:MM:SS. Wonder why this one hasn't done that?

Comment: It is odd that it shows 266 hours instead of DD:HH:MM:SS.  Never seen that on any 2008 server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks *about* right to me.

[image: boot time]

Different areas of the operating system may use different counters and slightly different arithmetical formulae and different levels of rounding/precision.  The "Task Manager" guy and the "systeminfo" guy probably aren't arriving at the same "up time" in exactly the same way.  But they're both "close enough."

I like this little blog post from Raymond Chen as an illustrative example of what I mean:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/11/13/10572050.aspx

Or maybe I overthought this and you simply thought that the "266" referred to days instead of hours.

Comment: `you simply thought that the "266" referred to days instead of hours` Yup... all my other servers displayed DD:MM:HH:SS so this one just ticked me. Thanks everyone!